# How to implement the type checking of `transp` in de Morgan cubical type theory?

Tags: implementation, cubical-type-theory

I am reading many referential materials and I want to find a proper way to implement it. Suppose the syntax is ${\sf transp}~A~\psi:A~0\to A~1$, where (let's call it "the condition") $A:\mathbb I \to \mathcal U$ is constant when $\psi=1$. I am looking for a criterion to check "the condition". For example, if $i\land j\lor k \land (\neg l)=1$, then what? What should I do to $A$? My guesses are as follows:

- I understand how to deal with the simplest case, where $\psi$ is a constant or just a variable. Those cases are obvious.
- If $\psi=i\land j$, I guess this will decompose "the condition" into the problems "when $i=1$, is $A$ constant?" and "$j=1$, is $A$ constant?", am I right?
- If $\psi=\neg i$, this is probably the same as $\psi=i$, but I'm also unsure.
- What to do when $\psi=i \lor j$?

I have checked some papers:

- In [Cubical Agda: A Dependently Typed
  Programming Language with Univalence and
  Higher Inductive Types](https://staff.math.su.se/anders.mortberg/papers/cubicalagda2.pdf), the rules for type checking are omitted, and is discussed informally.
- In [A CUBICAL TYPE THEORY FOR HIGHER INDUCTIVE
  TYPES](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Esimonhu/misc/hcomp.pdf), they wrote $\Gamma,i:\mathbb I,\psi \vdash A=A(i/0)$. Does this imply $\Gamma,\psi\vdash A(i/0)=A(i/1)$? Also, how to implement $\Gamma,\psi\vdash a=b$ for any term $a, b$ in general?
- In [On Higher Inductive Types in Cubical Type Theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.01170.pdf), "the condition" is described as $\psi\Rightarrow \forall(i:\mathbb I)A(0)=A(i)$ (I paraphrased the notation for consistency), and that essentially leads me to the same confusion as for hcomp.pdf.

Answers I'm expecting:

- Pointers to particular sections/page number of papers. I may miss some information while reading these papers.
- A few sentences like 'you traverse the syntax tree of $\psi$, and in case of this you substitute this to this and in case of that you substitute this to this, and then perform a MLTT conversion check between this and this'. This would greatly help me.
- Links to specific functions in implemented de Morgan cubical type theory. Existing codebases are large, and it's very easy to get lost.

Comment: Naïvely this should work: If $\neg i = 1$, then substitute $i \mapsto 0$; if $i \vee j = 1$, then substitute $i \mapsto 1$ and $j \mapsto 1$ simultaneously; if $i \wedge j = 1$, then split into two cases where $i = 1$ and $j = 1$, respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example, if $i∧j∨k∧(¬l)=1$, then what? What should I do to $A$?

As Trebor said, for $ i_1 ∧ i_2 ∧ … ∧ i_n = 1 $ we should perform n substitutions and check that $ A(i_1/1, i_2/1, …, i_n/1) = A(i_1/1, i_2/1, …, i_n/1, i/0) $. Further, each $ i ∨ j = 1 $ splits into two cases: $ i = 1 $ and $ j = 1 $; and for $ ¬i = 1 $ you should check $ i = 0 $.

But for cases like $ (i ∨ j) ∧ k = 1 $ it is tricky in general to do some checks directly this way, so in cubicaltt [formulas](https://github.com/mortberg/cubicaltt/blob/hcomptrans/Connections.hs#L133-L137) are first converted by [invFormula](https://github.com/mortberg/cubicaltt/blob/hcomptrans/Connections.hs#L239-L245) (weird name) to DNF stored as list of maps (each map represents conjunction in the form $ (i_1 = j_1) ∧ (i_2 = j_2) ∧ … ∧ (i_n = j_n) $, where $i_k$ are some variables and $ j_k ∈ \{0,1\} $). Then checker [simply iterates](https://github.com/mortberg/cubicaltt/blob/hcomptrans/TypeChecker.hs#L500-L507) over these maps simultaneously replacing each $i_k$ with $j_k$ and checking required condition. But notice that unlike Cubical Agda dimension variables in cubicaltt are special kind of syntax, so there can be no face like $(w.1 = 0)$ for some $w : \mathbb{I} × \mathbb{I}$ at all.

Cubical Agda [works about the same](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/master/src/full/Agda/TypeChecking/Rules/Application.hs#L1474-L1477): [`equalTermOnFace`](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/master/src/full/Agda/TypeChecking/Conversion.hs#L2020-L2021) calls `compareTermOnFace`, `compareTermOnFace` calls `compareTermOnFace'`, `compareTermOnFace'` calls `forallFaceMaps`, `forallFaceMaps` [checks some conditions](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/master/src/full/Agda/TypeChecking/Conversion.hs#L1888-L1914) for each conjunct obtained from [`decomposeInterval`](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/master/src/full/Agda/TypeChecking/Primitive/Cubical.hs#L1790-L1818) (which seems) analogous to `invFormula` in cubicaltt, only with the difference that it is necessary to handle faces like $(w.1 = 0)$.

> In [A CUBICAL TYPE THEORY FOR HIGHER INDUCTIVE TYPES](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Esimonhu/misc/hcomp.pdf), they wrote $Γ,i:I,ψ⊢A=A(i/0)$. Does this imply $Γ,ψ⊢A(i/0)=A(i/1)$?

We have $A = A(i/0)$ for each $i : I$, so isn’t it obvious that then $A(i/1) = (A(i/0))(i/1) = A(i/0)$? Also notice that converse doesn’t hold.

> Also, how to implement $Γ,ψ⊢a=b$ for any term $a,b$ in general?

Obviously, described things can be generalized from $A = A(i/0)$ to arbitrary $a = b$.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm very happy to hear that cubicaltt uses NDF because I'm also experimenting with DNF...